# Getting nth date from a table of "valid" dates

Tags: mysql, date, limit

I have a table that contains nothing but dates for the next 20 years. I use this table as a quick lookup to determine certain information about a date in relation to my application - for example, if the date is a holiday, if the date has been flagged with a certain indicator, etc.

What I'm trying to do is pull the nth valid day from my table, starting at a specified date. Essentially, I just update a value with the returned value of a limited subquery. Here is my code so - I'm getting an error on the limit.

```
UPDATE _piece_detail
INNER JOIN mail_classes 
   ON mail_classes.class_id = _piece_detail.class_id
SET _piece_detail.est_delivery_date = 
(SELECT date_value FROM date_lookup 
WHERE date_value >= _piece_detail.date_prepared AND holiday != 1 
LIMIT mail_classes.max_days,1)
WHERE est_delivery_date IS NULL;
```

I've tried casting `mail_classes.max_days` into an integer, but still no luck. I need this to be variable, since the number of days I need to count are based on the mail class.

Comment: Store it in a user-defined variable.  `SET @max_dates := ...` and then reference that from the `LIMIT` clause:  `LIMIT @max_dates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a function and using that with my routine. The function is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sample`@`%` FUNCTION `get_valid_date`(start_date DATE, added_days INT) RETURNS date
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     DECLARE new_date DATE;

    SELECT date_value 
    FROM date_tbl
    WHERE date_tbl.date_value >= start_date
        AND date_tbl.day_of_week != 1
    LIMIT added_days,1
    INTO new_date;

     RETURN new_date;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
(SELECT min(date_value) FROM date_lookup 
 WHERE date_value >= _piece_detail.date_prepared AND holiday != 1)
```

This will return the first non-holiday after the given date.

If you are concerned about performance, add a new column to the table "nextNonHoliday" and precalculate these values.

Comment: This might work for the NEXT valid date, however I am looking for the nth valid date based on the max_days column.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT cannot have variable parameters, they must be constant. So it cannot be either a table field value or a user-defined variable. I suggest the following solution:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
UPDATE _piece_detail
INNER JOIN mail_classes 
ON mail_classes.class_id = _piece_detail.class_id
SET _piece_detail.est_delivery_date = 
(
  SELECT date_value FROM 
  (
    SELECT date_value,(@rownum:=@rownum+1) AS rownum FROM date_lookup 
    WHERE date_value >= _piece_detail.date_prepared AND holiday != 1 
  ) 
  AS t_tmp
  WHERE t_tmp.rownum = mail_classes.max_days
)
WHERE est_delivery_date IS NULL;
```